# Sugar in canned sweet potatoes. can I remove it simply at home?

Tags: sugar

I have canned sweet potatoes that have sugar added.

Can I boil / bake / soak / ANYTHING to remove the added sugar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If these are canned whole sweet potato, or pieces/slices in syrup or sugar then yes, you can remove the sugar by rinsing the pieces in water. Whole pieces of sweet potato don't absorb sugar, it stays on the surface. The sugar is there as a preservative, believe it or not, not to make the potatoes sweeter. They could use salt but then that would clash with the flavor of the potatoes. You may get a little bit of sugar remaining but it will be very small.

On the other hand if it is some sort of processed sweet potato mash then there's no way to get rid of the sugar, it's there for good.

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate it yes they are chunks of sweet potato (not mashed), looks like the potato was peeled and sliced into a few chunks