# Removing sugar from condensed milk?

Tags: sugar

Is it possible to remove sugar from condensed milk?
I got by accident instead of evaporated milk.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, **no**, at least not if you want to use the end product as milk.

As [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/108379/22591) to a previous question of yours suggests, once the sugar is dissolved in a liquid or purée, there is no way to get it out. You can technically separate the sugar from the liquid (See [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40905/is-it-possible-to-separate-remove-sugar-from-common-drinks-such-as-juice) and its answers on the Chemistry stack exchange) but I don't believe any of the suggested methods (such as evaporating off the liquid, or fermenting out the sugars) will work for you here.